# Android ActionBar API, getSupportActionBar() and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnable meaning?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I added a icon on the action bar. And when i click on it, it opens another activity via intent. However, in some source, people add getSupportActionBar and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnable. Even if without those, it still works.

My question is what is the meaning og these 2 API?

Comment: Those are called methods in our Java language, not API.

Comment: ok thanks, but please help me with the concepts behind them please

Comment: You can check my answer now

Comment: thanks so much man. would you recommend an simple app idea fir me to practice these concepts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have included `actionBar` or `toolbar` in your `activity` and if you want to go to previous activity on the tap of *back arrow* on the left side (in LTR configuration) of your actionbar, you will have to first get actionbar as,

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
```

and then provide action which is *go to previous activity* and for that you will have to call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` method as,

```
if (ab != null) {
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```